# Как извлечь данне из бд, чтобы получился массив, где нужные мне поля стали ключем и значением соответственно?

Tags: php, ооп, codeigniter

Составляю запрос в таком виде:

```
$fieldsArr = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('status' => 1))->result_array();
```

на выходе получаю массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pfld_id] => 1
            [pfld_name] => last_name
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pfld_id] => 2
            [pfld_name] => name
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pfld_id] => 3
            [pfld_name] => otchestvo
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pfld_id] => 4
            [pfld_name] => sex
            [pfld_status] => 1
            [pfild_group_id] => 1
        )
```

но мне нужно чтобы массив выглядил так:

```
Array (
    [last_name] = 1
    [otchestvo] = 3
    [sex] = 4
)
```

могу конечно обойти массив и собрать новый, как мне надо но наверняка задачу можно решить еще на первом шаге с помощью конструктора запросов. Хочется чтобы все таки было максимально коротко и эффективно

Comment: Какую `ORM` вы используете?

Comment: @Klimenkomud `ActiveRecord CI` - это очевидно -.-

Comment: Я не эксперт в `sql`, но навряд-ли.

Comment: @Manitikyl Кому как, я про эту `ORM` слышу впервые. И с `ORM`-кой это по идее должно быть не слишком трудно. Да и в чистом `sql` конструкцию типа `SELECT "column_name" AS "this_name_more_comfortable_to_me" FROM "table_name"" вполне легко составить.

Comment: @Klimenkomud возможно эта страница позволит найти ответ на ваш вопрос http://codeigniter3.info/guide/database/query_builder

Comment: @Klimenkomud С каких это пор вы не слышали про `ActiveRecord`? Очень распространен. Просто `ActiveRecord` - существует в разных реализациях.

Comment: @Manitikyl Вообще, `ActiveRecord` - это паттерн проектирования `ORM`, а вот уже `ActiveRecord CI` - частная реализация для фреймворка `CodeIgniter`. И да, я не слышал про эту орм, т.к. уже давно не пишу на пхп, а когда писал - орм не использовал (да и с БД толком не работал)

Comment: @Klimenkomud я знаю о чем речь. спасибо)) Смешные Вы. А на чем вы сейчас пишете, тоже `ORM` не используете? По факту всего 2 популярных, `AC` и маппер, остальные по пальцам одной руки можно пересчитать, поэтому я не знаю как вы там не сталкивались.

Comment: @Manitikyl Использую, только при чем тут частный случай конкретной ормки на пхп? Вы вроде как на пхп пишете, это всё равно что я сейчас начну затирать про "Как это вы не слышали про `SQLAlchemy`? А про `Django ORM`? И про `mongoose` не слышали? И ДАЖЕ ПРО `pg`?

Comment: @Manitikyl Уверен, что названия приведенных мною `ORM` вам практически ничего не сказали. Зачастую, у ормок свои "внутренности", своё апи. И две ормки, написанных по одному паттерну могут иметь кардинально различное апи.

Comment: @Klimenkomud :D Полегче на поворотах, ковбой! Вы даже в терминах теряетесь. `ORM` - это идея (паттерн), у этой идеи есть реализация (может быть несколько). Если мы говорим об `ActiveRecord` то реализация у `CI`, `Laravel`, `Yii` у всех своя, но `ORM - ActiveRecord`. Вот я вам дам наводку, `SQLAlchemy` - не является `ORM`. Вот и думайте теперь :) P.S. `Django ORM` - Тоже не является паттерном

Comment: @Manitikyl Экий вы определитель терминов, книг случайно не пишете ? :D Если у вас своё, абстрактное представление того, что такое `ORM`, это не значит что везде так. По поводу `SQLAlchemy` - видимо даже не потрудились на хоум пейдж зайти, там прямо таки в начале страницы большими буквами - `The Python SQL Toolkit and Object Relational Mapper`.  `ActiveRecord` - это не `ORM`, это паттерн реализации, как и `DataMapper`. Технология `ORM` и паттерн реализации технологии `ORM`, чувствуете разницу?

Comment: @Klimenkomud почему я вас должен учить? Давайте по другому, более доступно: создайте любой класс и в нем метод который сделает запрос - уже можно говорить что вы написали `ORM`. НО существуют паттерны `ORM`. Вот Ваш `SQLAlchemy` - реализует паттерн `DataMapper`, а `Django ORM` - реализуает `ActiveRecord`. Когда они у себя используют слово `ORM` - как раз и подразумевается наличие реализации какого-то `ORM-паттерна`.

Comment: @Klimenkomud `паттерн реализации технологии ORM`. После такого, спор можно считать закрытым. Знайте как знаете)

Comment: @Manitikyl `метод который сделает запрос` - рили? `ORM` создает виртуальную обьектную модель БД, так сказать "мапает" БД к вашим классам, а не просто "делает запрос".

Comment: @Manitikyl В любом случае, эта дисскуссия вообще никак не касается данного вопроса, благодарю вас за потраченное на меня время, хорошего вам дня :)

Comment: @Klimenkomud я вам привел банально-сокращенный пример, чтобы не расписывать на 300 слов. `class->id = 'test'; class->method();`. И можете считать себя крутым разработчиком который написал `orm`)))))) Удачного и Вам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну долго пробегать не придется, достаточно так:

```
$array = array_column($fieldsArr, 'pfld_id', 'pfld_name');
var_dump($array);
```

Вместо `$fieldsArr` можете сразу пихать ваш запрос :)

---

Документация - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php